# Open own app from address book

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

The Address book in iOS has IM and Social integrations for redirecting users to the relevant apps, by using `kABPerson...` keys. For example the following are used to redirect to a certain contact's profile in relevant app with their respective keys:

> Facebook Messanger : kABPersonInstantMessageServiceFacebook
>
> Google Hangouts : kABPersonInstantMessageServiceGoogleTalk
>
> Yahoo Messenger : kABPersonInstantMessageServiceYahoo
>
> Facebook app : kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFacebook
>
> Twitter app : kABPersonSocialProfileServiceTwitter

Is there a way I can use my app's URL Scheme to redirect the user to my own app from inside a contact in the address book?

Comment: I don't think there is because the keys you mentioned are defined in system frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "URL" field in the address book, although it will show the full custom URL.

Just enter your custom URL scheme in the field and it will work